# iOS: Maintaining the communication failure state and update to all other classes

Tags: ios

I am developing a chat application, where i have multiple view controller classes. I also have a generic class where communication is happening between server and client. This communication class never know which view controller is been accessed it, because it is been accessed by all the view controllers for different reasons. In this situation, I am in need of updating the states like 'connection failed', 'internet failure', 'data failed', 'chat communication failed' like that to all the view controllers as soon as such errors happening at the communication class. I am thinking to solve by this having a flag setting in a singleton class and access it anywhere else (or) have a protocol (which is very secured than singleton) and set the status flag in communication class, and other view controllers can implement this protocol method to know the current status.

Could someone advise me whether i'm thinking at the right angle to implement and can achieve with these approaches?

Comment: Think about using notifications - your scenario is the classical playground for 1ton communication and a great tool for that is NSNotification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at notifications, which are intended for general distribution to multiple instances exactly like this.  See the docs for `NSNotificationCenter`.

Notifications are not just for hardware events, as you seem to misunderstand.  They are a general purpose broadcast mechanism to distribute information, just as delegation is a general purpose mechanism to allow an individual object to manage another objects behaviour.

In other words, your communications handler should post a notification of state change, and your other controllers should all register to receive that notification, and can respond however is appropriate for them.

Post example; put this when your file has finished loading:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PDLAssetManagerAssetFileLoaded" object:self];
```

And in each controller that needs to update itself when loading is complete, put:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadComplete:) name:@"PDLAssetManagerAssetFileLoaded" object:nil];
```

where `loadComplete:` is a method that takes the notification as an argument, and does whatever you need it to do.  You can pass extra data using the userInfo dictionary, which I have ignored here.  **Hot tip**: make the notification name string a constant; I skipped this in the interest of brevity.

Comment: Yeah, i know about Notification. But, how does it useful in my case. Basically, Notification is used to notify when some event is happening like keyboard launch, native apps are modified, device orientation changed like that. How can that help my problem? And, why can't i go with protocol which is also the right way?

Comment: @Getsy if more than one object needs to know something happened, delegates and protocols are not the right choice. Observer pattern (and its implementation in NSNotificationCenter) is the appropriate solution here. You say your view controllers all need to be notified that something has happened - why do you find this distinct than any other notification? That is, what is your objection to notifications? It is the classic, least headache solution to your problem.

Comment: It seems futile to use a delegate with protocol (the two aren't necessarily connected) hacked up to act like a notification when you could just use a notification.  Like I said, read the docs so you can get to understand what notifications are intended for.  I will expand my answer to give more detail.

Comment: Hi Paul, I'll read it surely. Also, please provide some samples how i can use it, that would also be great help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for NSNotificationCenter, you can use this;

1- Implement a delegate to your communication class.

2- Implement the callback when the requested case happens (etc. connection failure)

3- set your application delegate as the delegate of your communication class

4- When the callback happens, see which view controller you are on from your application delegate, and take action.

Comment: Yeah, this is what i asked for 'protocol' implementation, the same one. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that will help a lot more if you could provide!

Comment: what are you using for connection? NSURLConnection or asihttp?